# Cross entropy loss increase but precision get better

Tags: machine-learning, neural-network, classification, data-mining

i am working on classification model.

my test result shows precision is getting better despite loss is increase.

[image: loss]

[image: precision]

is it just the nature of my data or is there some kind of theoretical explanation?

Comment: Where do you see the test precision getting better? It seems to me that it stabilizes after roughly 30 iterations, plus minus random variation.

Comment: Is your dataset balanced? If there are too many samples of a class, you can have high precision even when the network is not learning much...